# Why a discrete group of diffeomorphisms $\mathbb S^2\rightarrow\mathbb S^2$ can't have exactly one fixed point?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, fixed-point-theorems, spheres

Context: while reading Thurston's notes on the geometry of 3-manifolds, I have found the assertion that the orbifold obtained from a sphere by adding a single conic point is a bad orbifold. However, his argument relies on the nonexistence of a discrete group of diffeomorphisms of the sphere fixing exactly one point.

How can we prove this? I thought that there should be an easy argument involving properties of degrees of maps between spheres that should clarify the situation, but I have not found it.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Actually, it can happen that such a diffeomorphism has exactly one fixed point, namely, a parabolic Moebius transformation of the Riemann sphere, $z\mapsto z+1$.

Comment: Ah, I see... I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, that's a very different claim. There are many way to prove this, for instance, do you know that every prime order homeomorphism of $R^2$ has a fixed point?

Comment: Consider writing an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll follow Moishe Kohan's indication.

Suppose that the teardrop orbifold is indeed a good orbifold. That means, after realizing that the only orbifold covers of a cone is a cone of order dividing that of the original one, that the universal covering orbifold of the tesrdrop is a sphere, and that it can be realized as a quotient of the sphere by a discrete group of diffeomorphisms. Now the isotropy group of the cone point $x$ is finite, and the restriction of all the diffeomorphisms that fix $x$ to $\mathbb S^2\setminus\{x\}$ determines, after composing them with the stereographic projection, a finite group of diffeomorphisms of the plane. After choosing an element of prime order $f$, a classical theorem of Smith then assures that the group generated by $f$ must fix a point of $\mathbb R^2$. But then, pulling back the group $\langle f\rangle$ by precomposing with the inverse of the stereographic projection gives rise to a subgroup of the isotropy group of $x$ that fixes another point of the sphere, a contradiction.

Comment: In dimension 2 you can avoid using Smith Theory. Instead, observe that there are no surfaces with finite nontrivial fundamental group and universal covering space $R^2$.